# How to implement a file chooser and that can actually access the desired file in downloads or documents folder Android (Kotlin) API 33+?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create an app for my small business (only 3 people) that allows a user (me) to choose a csv file, have it convert the data, and save it as a new csv. I am able to successfully read and manipulate the data from a file I brought directly into android studio, and I have a working file chooser that can access the recent documents. However, I cannot select any files in the documents or downloads folder. Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Added extra code and clarified the part I'm having issues with.

Here is the code I have for the file chooser. I'll be completely honest and say I found most of this code online and don't fully exactly how it works since most of the android documentation and examples show deprecated versions

```
    private var uriToFile:String = "Path"



    private var fileImportCompletionHandler: (Uri.()->Unit)? = null

    private val fileImportIntentLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result: ActivityResult ->

            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                val intent = result.data
                intent?.data?.let { uri ->

                    Log.i("MYTAG","uri at first check is $uri")
                    fileImportCompletionHandler?.invoke(uri) ?: run {
                        // TODO() warn

                    }

                    fileImportCompletionHandler = null
                   val p = uri.path
                    Log.i("MYTAG","p is $p")
                    


                } ?: run {
                    // TODO() warn

                }

            }
            else {
                // TODO() warn
            }

        }

    private val importIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {

        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "text/csv"

    }


fun showActionOpenDocument(completion: Uri.()->Unit) {

        fileImportCompletionHandler = completion
        fileImportIntentLauncher.launch(importIntent)

    }
```

Here is where I call it

```
binding.btnImport.setOnClickListener {
            //requestPermission()
            showActionOpenDocument {
                uriToFile = this.toString()
                binding.tvPath.text = uriToFile
            }
```

Here is how I call the read (actual computing and manipulation done elsewhere)

```
fun readCSV(path:String): BufferedReader {
        val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(path))
        //return BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(assets.open("Test.csv")))

        return BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

    }
```

Here is the section in the android manifest for the permissions. I do not actually need to access the camera, however the request permissions dialog doesn't even show up with the storage ones so I was checking if a different permission works. It does

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Here is all the actual permission stuff (I have swapped all permissions around. Camera is the only permission that will even pop up

```
 private val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
            Log.i("MYTAG", "isGranted = true")

        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their

        }
    }

fun requestPermission(){
    when{
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            vContext,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
            //Permission is Granted

            Log.i("MYTAG","Permission Granted")

        }
        ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            vActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) -> {
            //Permission denied : Additional Rational should be displayed
            Log.i("MYTAG","Permission Denied")
            showRationaleDialog("TCG Inventory Converter",
                "TCG Inventory Converter needs access to your External Storage"+
                        "\n"+"\n"+"REASON: Required to import and export CSV Files ")

        }
        else -> {
            // Permission has not been asked yet
            Log.i("MYTAG","Permission Requested")
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        }
    }
}

private fun showRationaleDialog(title:String, message:String){
    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(vContext)
    builder.setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton("Cancel"){ dialog, _->
         dialog.dismiss()
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Open Permissions"){ dialog, _ ->
            dialog.run {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                val uri = Uri.fromParts("package","com.example.filereadtest",null)
                intent.data =uri
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        }
    builder.create().show()
}
```

[Image of non selectable file that I want selectable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XodMv.jpg)

[Image of only selectable location I can find (can't save files here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKQV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

```kotlin
intent?.data?.let { uri ->
  contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { stream ->
    // do something useful
  }
}
```

Ideally, you would hand the `Uri` off to a viewmodel or something that can do the content I/O on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you for this. I implemented this and it works much better. I have updated the post to no longer include this part of the problem. Still need to be able to access the documents and/or the downloads folder

Comment: @LetsGoRidePandas: "I have updated the post to no longer include this part of the problem" -- that is not a good way to use this site. If you have new/different questions, ask a separate question.

Comment: it's still the same question, I just realized I didn't word it properly/include as much info as I should've. My bad